# How to let mysql docker start even if entrypoint scripts fail

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a bunch of sql scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` which I am developing in a Docker container `FROM ubuntu/mysql:8.0-22.04_beta`

The container will not start if one of the scripts causes an error.

I want the container to continue to start even if an entrypoint script fails, then I want to get a shell in and poke around.

How can I tell it to do this?

Comment: I DO NOT suggest allowing it but if you must try adding this flag :
-f, --force        .  As far as a shell and poke around, can you get MySQL Workbench going in a container?  If you can, that is the best way I suspect.

Comment: There is no meaningful way to do what you propose. Use `docker logs` to find out why the container failed. Then fix your script and run a new container.

Comment: Do these scripts need to be tied to the only-on-first run database setup?  Can you run them in something like a database migration system, which will support re-running them and isn't specifically tied to Docker?